# New 7900 XTX and 5800X3D, Having trouble with microstuttering as low as 1 FPS

Tags: gaming

I am able to achieve an average FPS of 120 in most games, but whether I turn the resolution down from 4k to 1080p, or limit the frame rate to 60, I am having microstutters all the way down to single digit FPS.

Using Adrenalin to check on my CPU/GPU utilization, neither of which reach over 50%. I have done a full reinstall of windows and that has not resolved the issues.

Power: Corsair RMX850W
Memory: Corsair Vengeance 32gb 3600 mhz

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated as I'm going a bit insane at this point.